# Java 11 + Docker Based App = `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory`

Tags: java, jvm, apache-flink, flink-streaming

With a Flink 1.14.3 application running on Kubernetes using the `flink:1.14.3-scala_2.12-java11` Docker image, I'm getting this Java memory error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
    at java.base/java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:648)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:623)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:202)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.tcacheAllocateSmall(PoolArena.java:172)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:134)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:126)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:394)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:188)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:179)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:140)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.dns.DatagramDnsQueryEncoder.allocateBuffer(DatagramDnsQueryEncoder.java:82)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.dns.DatagramDnsQueryEncoder.encode(DatagramDnsQueryEncoder.java:60)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.dns.DatagramDnsQueryEncoder.encode(DatagramDnsQueryEncoder.java:33)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:89)
    ... 52 more
```

This is specifically happening with the VertX version 4.2.4 async Postgresql client which is using the Netty async http engine.

The specific version of java is:

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Are there any JVM or Docker or Kubernetes parameters I should try tweaking to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried with java 17?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm using the latest supported versions of everything. The latest Flink and the latest supported Java. The current version of Apache Flink doesn't support Java 17 yet, so that isn't an option. They will eventually, supposedly for 1.16 towards the end of 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task manager memory layout and configuration options are described in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/memory/mem_setup_tm/.